# scrape table generated by a script

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape a website table with python and beautiful soup. The problem I'm having is that the table was generated via a script so the table looks like the following:

```
<table class="table table-compact table-striped table-topics">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-intro="Clicking a topic will allow you to view and ask general technical questions about the topic through SITIS." data-position="bottom">Topic #</th>
                    <th>Program</th>
                    <th>Component</th>
                    <th>Technology Area</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th data-intro="If there is SITIS activity for a topic a clickable 'QA' will appear in this column." data-position="bottom">SITIS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each this.Results}}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="/topics?topicId={{this.TopicId}}" target="_blank" data-topicid="{{this.TopicId}}">{{this.TopicNumber}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{this.ProgramTypeName}}</td>
                    <td>{{this.AgencyName}}</td>
                    <td>

                      <div class="icons">
                        {{#if this.TechAreaAirPlatform}}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-air-platform" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Air Platform"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaChemBioDefense }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-chem-bio-defense" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Chem Bio Defense"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaInfoSystems}}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-info-systems" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Info Systems"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaGroundSea }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-ground-sea" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Ground Sea"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaMaterials}}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-materials" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Materials"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaBioMedical }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-bio-med" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Bio Medical"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaSensors }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-sensors" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Sensors"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaElectronics }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-electronics" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Electronics"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaBattlespace }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-battlespace" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Battlespace"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaSpacePlatforms }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-space-platform" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Space Platforms"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                          {{#if this.TechAreaHumanSystems }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-human-systems" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Human Systems"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaWeapons }} 
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-weapons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Weapons"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{#if this.TechAreaNuclear }}
                          <i class="glyph-icon flaticon-nuclear" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Technology Area: Nuclear"></i>
                        {{/if}}
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="/topics?topicId={{this.TopicId}}" target="_blank" data-topicid="{{this.TopicId}}">{{this.TopicTitle}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{#if this.PublishedQuestionCount}}<a href="/topics?topicId={{this.TopicId}}" target="_blank" data-topicid="{{this.TopicId}}">Q&A</a>{{/if}}</td>
                </tr>
                {{else}}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6"><div class="alert alert-warning">No topics were found.</div></td>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I was wondering if someone knew if it is still feasible to scrape the table. there is a script tag immediately preceeding the table that I wondered if it would be of use.

```
<script id="topics-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: I ran in to a similar problem using c# and found selenium webdriver a good way to scrape this. It physically opens a browser and loads the JavaScript which you can then scrape through built in methods (getElement and innerText etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion in the comments to use selenium WebDriver is a probably the simplest workaround for your problem. It looks like you're trying to scrape a site that is dynamically generating content with Django templates, or something similar.

So you need to emulate a browser in order to actually load all of the content on the page since you're currently only getting the static html. You can install selenium with you package manager, then you need to install the driver for the browser you want to impersonate:

```
pip install selenium
pip install chromedriver
```

Note: not all web drivers can be installed with your package manager (I don't think) so you might have to download it from the regular internet.

Now you can use something such as this function I've written to scrape your desired page:

```
# purpose: a function which takes a url and extracts the contents as a string
# depends on selenium webdriver to turn js-scripts into html as well as time and os libraries
# signature: pull_html_page(url:string, write:optional boolean) -> string 
def pull_html_page(url, write = False):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(1)
    content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')

    driver.quit()


    if write == True:
        # the "my dick computer won't let me be root" workaround
        if os.geteuid() == 0:
            print("We're root!")
        else:
            print("We're not root.")
            CURRENT_SCRIPT = os.path.realpath(__file__)
            os.system('echo ' + PASSWORD_FOR_SUDO + '|sudo -S python '+ CURRENT_SCRIPT)

            clean = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser").prettify()

            f = open("out.html", "w+")
            f.write(clean)
            f.close()

    return content
```

If this solution isn't efficient enough for you, or you only need the dynamically generated data and nothing from the static html. You can often use your inspect tool (I prefer the one on chrome) to see the network traffic. Sometimes you can see the url that is returning the JSON response, doing this saves you the time of loading the page, and you can scrape the data directly from the response url.

good luck!